# Getting optional String from singleton

Tags: swift, string, singleton, nsuserdefaults, option-type

I've created a class with some vars and lets. One of these vars is a `String`. I store them in `UserDefaults`. If I want to access the string of this class over a singleton class, I will always get an optional String. I don't know why.

Here is the class of the object:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class BallSkinsClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let id: Int
    var name: String
    var isBuyed: Bool

    let ID = "id"
    let NAME = "name"
    let ISBUYED = "isBuyed"

    init(id: Int, name: String, isBuyed: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isBuyed = isBuyed
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: ID)
        self.name = String(describing: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: NAME))
        self.isBuyed = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: ISBUYED)
    }

    @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: ID)
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: NAME)
        aCoder.encode(isBuyed, forKey: ISBUYED)
    }
}
```

To declare the skins, access, save and load I have these functions in my BallSkinsClass:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameKit

class BallSkins {
    static var sharedInstance = BallSkins()

    private init() {
    }

    let BALLSKINS = "ballSkins"

    var standard: BallSkinsClass! = BallSkinsClass(id: 0, name: "Standard", isBuyed: true)
    var billiard: BallSkinsClass! = BallSkinsClass(id: 1, name: "Billard", isBuyed: false)
    var emoji: BallSkinsClass! = BallSkinsClass(id: 2, name: "Emojis", isBuyed: false)

    func archiveBallSkins(ballSkins:[BallSkinsClass]) -> NSData {
        print("archiving Skins")
        let archivedBallSkins = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ballSkins as Array)
        return archivedBallSkins as NSData
    }

    func saveBallSkins(ballSkins:[BallSkinsClass]) {
        let archivedBallSkins = archiveBallSkins(ballSkins: ballSkins)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedBallSkins, forKey: BALLSKINS)
        print("saving Skins")
    }

    func retrieveBallSkins() -> [BallSkinsClass]? {
        print("retrieving Skins")
        if let unarchivedBallSkins = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: BALLSKINS) as? NSData {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedBallSkins as Data) as? [BallSkinsClass]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func loadBallSkins() {
        print("loading Skins")
        let archivedBallSkins = retrieveBallSkins()
        for ballSkin in archivedBallSkins! {
            switch ballSkin.id {
            case 0 :
                standard.isBuyed = ballSkin.isBuyed
            case 1:
                billiard.isBuyed = ballSkin.isBuyed
            case 2:
                emoji.isBuyed = ballSkin.isBuyed
            default:
                standard.isBuyed = ballSkin.isBuyed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to access the name of the skin in any other scene or view I call:

```
ballSkins.sharedInstance.billiard.name
```

But this is an optional every time! I don't know why or where the error is.

Comment: The way you create standard and others is wrong.

Comment: `name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""`

Comment: @el tomato: would you be so kind to tell me why? maybe a hint how i could make it better would be nice! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is caused by

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: ID)
    self.name = String(describing: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: NAME))
    self.isBuyed = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: ISBUYED)
}
```

3rd line generates optional string because according to documentation

> func decodeObject() -> Any?

and String(describing: ...) does not unwrap your value. You must unwrap all values from UserDefaults by yourself, providing defaultValue if nil is not possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works now!